# Gatsby images from markdown posts not displaying from graphql query

Tags: image, graphql, markdown, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I built a blog with Gatsby and Tailwind using markdown for blog posts. When querying the data using graphql, I can't get any of the images to display. My images are stored within the `src/` directory in an `images/` folder. My posts are inside of a `pages/` folder within that same directory. At one point the site displayed ALL of the images including the ones in markdown, but wouldn't work when deployed to Netlify. I've gotten the site to deploy, but now none of my images are showing and I've tried everything to get them back. I've also tried using gatsby-image (fixed and fluid) and still nothing.

This is my first project with gatsby, markdown, and graphql. Currently, the deployed site [nikkipeel.netlify.app](https://nikkipeel.netlify.app) shows the proper path on the blog page for posts when inspected using devtools (../images/example.jpg), but still no image actually displays. ‍♀️

Github repo: [gatsby-blog](https://www.github.com/nikkipeel/gatsby-blog)

project structure:

```
|-- /public
|-- /src
    |-- /components
    |-- /pages
       |-- /post-one
          |--index.md
       |-- /post-two
          |--index.md
       |-- /post-three
          |--index.md
    |-- /templates
       |-- blog-post.js
    |-- /images

|-- /static
|-- gatsby-config.js
|-- gatsby-node.js
|-- gatsby-ssr.js
|-- gatsby-browser.js
```

frontmatter for a blog post (index.md) -

```
---
path: "/create-a-blog-with-react-and-sanity"
date: "2021-01-10"
title: "Create a blog with React and Sanity"
description: "Create a technical blog built with React, TailwindCSS, and Sanity then deploy it using Github and Netlify"
category: "React"
author: "Nikki Peel"
authorImage:  ../images/selfie.png
image: ../images/sanity-blog-collage.jpg
---
```

Blog.js with Graphql query for displaying all posts:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Link from 'gatsby-link';
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const BlogPage = ({ data }) => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Blog" />
    <main className="bg-brown text-white h-auto p-12">
            <section className="container mx-auto">
                <h1 className="text-4xl mono pl-4">Latest Blog Posts</h1>
                <h2 className="text-lg mb-12 pl-4">Welcome to my page of blog posts</h2>


                <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 justify-center mx-auto md:gap-8 mb-24"> 
                {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(post => (
                   <article>
                   <Link to={post.node.frontmatter.path}>
    
                   <div className="block lg:h-64 relative leading-snug" key={ post.node.id }>
                   <img src={post.node.frontmatter.image} alt="" className="lg:block w-full items-center lg:h-full lg:object-cover lg:object-top relative lg:absolute"/> 
                       <span className="block relative lg:h-full lg:flex lg:items-end ">
                           <h3 className="lg:bg-gray-800 lg:bg-opacity-75 text-white text-xl font-semibold lg:px-3 lg:py-4 rounded text-left">{post.node.frontmatter.title}</h3>
                       </span>
                      <div className="mt-4 mb-8"> 
                           <p className="text-base mb-4">{post.node.frontmatter.description}</p>
                           <span id={post.node.frontmatter.category} className="text-black font-semibold text-sm py-2 px-4 mr-2 rounded">{post.node.frontmatter.category}</span>
                           <small className="text-base ml-2">&#128197; {post.node.frontmatter.date}</small>
                       </div> 
                   </div>
                   </Link>
               </article>
     ))}

               
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
  </Layout>
)

export const pageQuery = graphql`
    query BlogIndexQuery {
            allMarkdownRemark  (sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }){
                edges {
                    node {
                        id
                    frontmatter {
                        path
                        title
                        description
                        date
                        category
                        image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;

export default BlogPage;
```

And for Single Posts - blog-post.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Link from 'gatsby-link';
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faChevronLeft } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

export default function Template({ data }) {
    const post = data.markdownRemark

    return (
        <Layout>
              <main className="container bg-brown min-h-screen p-4 md:p-12">
            <Link to="/blog" exact className="text-white text-base items-center"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronLeft} className="mr-4"></FontAwesomeIcon> Back to Blog</Link>
            <article className="container text-white mx-auto rounded-lg mt-4">
                <header className="relative">
                    <div className="absolute h-full w-full flex items-center justify-center p-8">
                        <div className="bg-white text-brown bg-opacity-75 rounded p-4 md:p-12">
                            <h1 className="mono text-3xl mb-4">
                                {post.frontmatter.title}
                            </h1>
                            <div className="flex justify-center text-brown">
                                <img src={post.frontmatter.authorImage} alt="" className="w-10 h-10 rounded-full"/>
                                <p className="mono flex items-center pl-4 text-xl">{post.frontmatter.author}</p>
                            </div>
                            <p className="text-base font-semibold mt-4 text-center">Published on <strong>{post.frontmatter.date}</strong></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src={post.frontmatter.image} alt={post.frontmatter.title} className="w-full object-cover object-left-top rounded-t" style={{ height: "400px", width: "100%"}}/>
                </header>
                <div className="break-words px-4 lg:px-16 py-12 lg:py-20 prose lg:prose-xl max-w-screen leading-normal">
                    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
                </div>
            </article>
        </main>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export const postQuery = graphql`
    query BlogPostByPath($path: String!) {
        markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path } }){
            html
            frontmatter {
                path
                title
                date
                author
                authorImage 
                image
            }
        }
    }
`
```

When using the graphiql playground, the proper image path is retrieved for blog.js but not for blog-post.js (individual posts):

blog.js query:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allMarkdownRemark": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "frontmatter": {
              "path": "/customizing-the-scrollbar-with-css",
              "title": "Customizing the Scrollbar with CSS",
              "description": "Learn how to apply custom styling to the scrollbar on your project with pure CSS",
              "date": "2021-01-28",
              "category": "CSS",
              "image": "../images/scrollbar.png"
            }
          }
        },
```

blog-post.js query:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable \"$path\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 24
        }
      ],
      "stack": [
        "GraphQLError: Variable \"$path\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided.",
        "    at _loop (C:\\Users\\npeel\\Microsoft VS Code\\gatsby-blog-main\\gatsby-blog-main\\node_modules\\graphql\\execution\\values.js:92:17)",
        "    at coerceVariableValues (C:\\Users\\npeel\\Microsoft VS Code\\gatsby-blog-main\\gatsby-blog-main\\node_modules\\graphql\\execution\\values.js:119:16)",
        "    at getVariableValues (C:\\Users\\npeel\\Microsoft VS Code\\gatsby-blog-main\\gatsby-blog-main\\node_modules\\graphql\\execution\\values.js:48:19)",
        "    at buildExecutionContext (C:\\Users\\npeel\\Microsoft VS Code\\gatsby-blog-main\\gatsby-blog-main\\node_modules\\graphql\\execution\\execute.js:184:61)",
        "    at executeImpl (C:\\Users\\npeel\\Microsoft VS Code\\gatsby-blog-main\\gatsby-blog-main\\node_modules\\graphql\\execution\\execute.js:89:20)",
        "    at execute (C:\\Users\\npeel\\Microsoft VS Code\\gatsby-blog-main\\gatsby-blog-main\\node_modules\\graphql\\execution\\execute.js:64:35)",
        "    at C:\\Users\\npeel\\Microsoft VS Code\\gatsby-blog-main\\gatsby-blog-main\\node_modules\\express-graphql\\index.js:152:16",
        "    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "extensions": {}
}
```

gatsby-node.js -

*I received an error when adding 'image' and 'authorImage' to frontmatter here*

```
const path = require('path');

exports.createPages = ({actions, graphql}) => {
    const { createPage } = actions

    const postTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/blog-post.js');

    return graphql(`
        {
            allMarkdownRemark{
                edges {
                    node {
                        html
                        id
                    frontmatter {
                        path
                        title
                        date
                        author
                        category
                        description
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `).then(res => {
        if(res.errors) {
            return Promise.reject(res.errors)
        }

        res.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({node}) => {
            createPage({
                path: node.frontmatter.path,
                component: postTemplate
            })
        })
    })
}


// for RSS feed:
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value,
    })
  }
}
```

gatsby-config.js -

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Nikki Peel - Blog`,
    description: `Technical blog created with Gatsby and Markdown`,
    author: `Nikki Peel`,
    siteUrl: `https://nikkipeel.netlify.app`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-catch-links`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `pages`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },

    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/blog-logo.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-feed`,
    `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
    `gatsby-plugin-fontawesome-css`,
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/working-with-images-in-markdown/), the when dealing with markdown plus images, the paths should be relative to the markdown file itself so:

```
---
path: "/create-a-blog-with-react-and-sanity"
date: "2021-01-10"
title: "Create a blog with React and Sanity"
description: "Create a technical blog built with React, TailwindCSS, and Sanity then deploy it using Github and Netlify"
category: "React"
author: "Nikki Peel"
authorImage: /gatsby-blog/images/selfie.png
image: /gatsby-blog/images/sanity-blog-collage.jpg
---
```

*From post-one: https://github.com/nikkipeel/gatsby-blog/blob/main/src/pages/post-one/index.md*

Should become:

```
---
path: "/create-a-blog-with-react-and-sanity"
date: "2021-01-10"
title: "Create a blog with React and Sanity"
description: "Create a technical blog built with React, TailwindCSS, and Sanity then deploy it using Github and Netlify"
category: "React"
author: "Nikki Peel"
authorImage: ../../images/selfie.png
image: ../../sanity-blog-collage.jpg
---
```

Note the relativity of both images (`../../images/selfie.jpg`). This will allow Gatsby to create a valid GraphQL node and it will display the `childImageSharp` node in the GraphQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`).

> Field "image" must not have a selection since type "String" has no
> subfields. This can happen if you e.g. accidentally added { } to the
> field "image". If you didn't expect "image" to be of type "String"
> make sure that your input source and/or plugin is correct.

Unlike it may seem, this is a good error because it's pointing that Gatsby is trying to create nodes from your markdown files (i.e: your paths are well referenced now) and you will be able to use `gatsby-image`. I've realized that you are missing some plugins, according to the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/working-with-images-in-markdown/#using-the-transformer-remark-plugin).

Add the `gatsby-transformer-remark` and the `gatsby-remark-images` plugin.

```
`gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
{
  resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
  options: {
    plugins: [
      {
        resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
        options: {
          maxWidth: 800,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
},
```

---

I wouldn't put the markdown files in the `/pages` folder by Gatsby to avoid potential issues. Gatsby is a folder-structure based routing, or in other words, Gatsby infers the internal structure of the `/pages` folder to create the routing and the paths so it's better to avoid mixing stuff.

Your pages can be stored inside any folder if you set the `gatsby-source-filesystem` accordingly. This will allow Gatsby to create GraphQL nodes from those markdown files.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately changing the file paths didn't change the outcome.  All of the other markdown content is being loaded, along with the frontmatter (description, title, category, date). The only issue I'm having is with the images displaying. Is there anything else I should've done after changing to a relative path? Maybe I need to import gatsby-image and include childImageSharp in the query?

Comment: Can you try moving the transformers plugins (and remark) at the top of the plugins list?

Comment: I moved those plugins to the top of the config file and updated the github repo. After deploying to Netlify, I still receive 404 errors for all of my images. For the blog page (blog.js) the error is: 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()' for each image, no matter the file path specified in the markdown file. For individual posts, I still receive a 404 error, but it appears to come from a 'GET' request. I tried using childImageSharp in the image query, but then receive the error stating that 'image' cannot contain subfields.

Comment: The idea is to make the trials before pushing and deploying your site, in a local environment.  "tried using childImageSharp in the image query, but then receive the error stating that 'image' cannot contain subfields" --> This is good. This means that Gatsby found your image node but can't create a valid schema. So, this issue is new and should be treated differently. Your image folder should not contain any other asset than images, check the format and the extension (naming) of the assets, and upgrade Gatsby to latest version

Comment: I only have .png and .jpg files in the images folder now and am updated to the latest version of Gatsby (2.31.1). I've reconfigured blog.js and blog-post.js to use gatsby-image and childImageSharp. Error message in the terminal:
      Field "image" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields.

      This can happen if you e.g. accidentally added { } to the field "image". If you didn't expect "image" to be of type "String" make sure that your
 input source and/or plugin is correct.

Comment: I think you are missing two plugins: `gatsby-transformer-remark` and `gatsby-remark-images`. I've updated the question with a new trial (hope the last one)

Comment: I see the images! I added the plugin 'gatsby-remark-images' and imported 'gatsby-image' to both blog.js and blog-post.js. Next, I changed the queries to include childImageSharp along with 'fixed' and fluid' attributes. The images now display and it's only a matter of adjusting the styling to my preference now. The solution was: 1) ensure I had all necessary plugins installed 2) correct the file path within the markdown files to be relative and 3) use 'gatsby-image' with proper queries. Now I just need to adjust the styling, rebuild, and redeploy. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the images to load by referencing an external source in the markdown files but still can't access them by file path ‍♀️  I'm still researching and working on this issue

```
---
path: "/post-three"
date: "2020-11-23"
title: "My Third Gatsby Post"
description: "This is my third markdown post with gatsby"
category: "Tailwind"
author: "Nikki Peel"
authorImage: https://i.imgur.com/qyIekvV.png
image: https://i.imgur.com/lKnOCsT.jpg
---
```

Comment: Yes, that's another approach. However, I thought the idea was to use `gatsby-image`